# Implementing bootstrap select into an existing project

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I'm working with a massive code base here and trying to shoe horn in bootstrap-select to render in a nice fancy drop down. https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

We have bootstrap 3.0.0 and jquery 1.12.4 and from what I understand for bootstrap-select I need at least bootstrap 3.3.7 and I'm not quite sure how to go about updating bootstrap. We've got a public folder housing the current bootstrap js and css files.

I've found that adding

```
 <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Gives me the desired look for the drop downs but breaks the rest of the styling on the page. Honestly kind of lost for a direction here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After such a simple fix my brain hurts. I should have read the getting started page better... By adding the 2 lines below the styling is displaying correctly now.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.9/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I ended up getting these files added to our web pack configuration, everything works beautifully now

Answer (score 1):

For the newest version of bootstrap use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

For version 3.37 specifically, I believe you can just change the number in the link from 4.3.1 to your desired version.

Hope this helps!

You may also want to try this (with your version number) in the terminal

```
gem install bootstrap -v 4.3.1
```

Comment: Interesting that fixed most of the styling but now text is smaller

Comment: This is probably due to new features. I would check the documentation: [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/)